# Density estimation methods?

Tags: probability, estimation, nonparametric

What non-/semiparametric methods to estimate a probability density from a data sample are you using ?

(Please do not include more than one method per answer)

Comment: your experience -- has run on 1k / 100k points, in 1d / 2d / 3d -- would also be useful.

Answer (score 5):

[Dirichlet Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process) mixture models can be very flexible nonparametric Bayesian approach for density modeling, and can also be used as building blocks in more complex models. They are essentially an infinite generalization of parametric Gaussian mixture models and don't require specifying in advance the number of components in the mixture.

Answer (score 5):

Gaussian Processes can also be another nonparametric Bayesian approach for density estimation. See this [Gaussian Process Density Sampler](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.144.3937&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper.

Answer (score 3):

I use Silverman's Adaptive Kernel Density estimator. see e.g [`akj` help page](http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_current/library/quantreg/man/akj.html)

Answer (score 2):

Half-space depth a.k.a. bag-plots.

http://www.r-project.org/user-2006/Slides/Mizera.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A nice short paper by Jose Bernardo [here](http://www.uv.es/~bernardo/Kernel.pdf) gives a useful Bayesian method to estimate a density.  But as with most things Bayesian, the computational cost must be paid for this method.